# Azure ARM template for Communication Services API connection

Tags: azure, templates, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-communication-services

I would like to create an API connection for the Logic App to use Azure Communication Services (ACS) Email.
I want the ARM template to pull the ACS connection string from the keyvault during the deployment - this part works fine.

My problem is that I don't know the name of the field under which I should put the connection string in the ACS resource block.

Is it possible to list all valid options for `properties` or `parameterValues` for a specific resource?

I also to create it manually in the Azure Portal and then export the template, but no additional field for connection string appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the parameter name I was looking for using the Armclient (https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient).

The parameter name was `api_key`.

Comment: I did not find a reference in the linked repo but can confirm it is indeed api_key. Another way is to open F12 developer console in the browser. When you click on "API Connections", the corresponding call lists all the parameters and their internal names.

Comment: @RamanpreetSingh You won't find this information in the repo itself, but the ARMClient is a binary that allows you to obtain such information by querying the Azure Resource Manager API.